# Spfx extension Custom action component ids are specified by query parameters but matching manifests cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint, office365, spfx

I have create spfx extension Application Customizer for top navigation and footer. Then run 'gulp serve' command in terminal, but can't see header and footer on page in browser. In console below error found
**'Custom action component ids are specified by query parameters but matching manifests cannot be found. Ids: 0dc469d1-39bf-44a5-9cfd-fb7c0c7babbd'**

Please help me in this.

Thank in advance